# Converting WAV to MP3

Tags: java, audio, mp3, wav

I'm looking for a way to convert a WAV file, or ByteArrayOutputStream or AudioInputStream, to MP3.

I tried to find a MP3 encode library for AudioSystem but there was nothing with an example which helped me.

Then I looked for a small command line too which works on Debian, MacOS and Windows. I tried to find lame as a compiled file for each os, but found only one for Windows.

Is there any easy way to convert WAV to MP3 with Java? I don't mind for Java libraries (I prefer maven sources) or a compiled command line tool which I can put into my project. I'm not looking for a wrapper.

Comment: Did you try LAME ?

Comment: It's only for available for Windows as a compiled version

Comment: Nope. I'm using in Linux as a command line. Ubuntu (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lame) and many other distributions have this free software.

Comment: Well yes, but you installed it through the package manager, but I'm looking for the file itself

Comment: You need the binary file / executable? You can compile it from source or you can find it in library folder after installation.

Comment: Well that is what I don't want, because I don't have the compiler for it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [this](http://www.tritonus.org/plugins.html) library?
It has support for WAV.

Comment: I'm looking for something that supports MP3, WAV is not the problem. But thanks, I will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [PortAudio2](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/index.html) This is a C library but has multiple ports to Java, C#, C++, Python etc...

If PortAudio2 is not the way to go you can also take a look at [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) this is a multiplatform commandline tool to convert various formats to another format. If you just call this command inside your Java application it will probably work

Another option [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) some sort of java wrapper for FFMPEG. Also available as maven

Comment: there is no FFMPEG compiled version for each platform, I already looked a few hours for it :(

Comment: if you build specific versions for windows or mac or linux you cant just use the different FFMPEG. Think outside the box.

Comment: yes I know, I don't mind to use different versions but I'm still not able to compile them, because I don't have the compiler for it.

Comment: why not package prebuild binaries? and use these

Comment: I never used prebuild binaries, so I don't know how

Comment: Xuggler looks nice, but i can't find anything for converting audio files

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/

> JAVE
>   The JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library is Java wrapper on the ffmpeg project. Developers can take take advantage of JAVE to transcode audio and video files from a format to another. In example you can transcode an AVI file to a MPEG one, you can change a DivX video stream into a (youtube like) Flash FLV one, **you can convert a WAV audio file to a MP3** or a Ogg Vorbis one, you can separate and transcode audio and video tracks, you can resize videos, changing their sizes and proportions and so on. Many other formats, containers and operations are supported by JAVE.
>
> Requirements
>   JAVE requires a J2SE environment 1.4 or later and a Windows or Linux OS on a i386 / 32 bit hardware architecture. JAVE can also be easily ported to other OS and hardware configurations, see the JAVE manual for details.

Comment: I already found that and tried it. I'm getting always `Method threw 'it.sauronsoftware.jave.InputFormatException' exception.`. Sadly there is now help for correct input format

Comment: You found the examples and manual at http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php? It should work for normal wav files.

Comment: Yes, I created a wave mono file with Audacity and now I'm trying to convert it to mp3

Comment: JAVE is not pure java. Jump3r is.